# php mkdir not abiding by chmod rules i'm using

Tags: php, linux, permissions

I have this snippet which actually makes the dir, but it's permissions are set to 755 and not 777. Why is the mkdir command not working correctly?

```
$path = 'assets/images/photoAlbums/'.$album;
$test = mkdir($path, 0777);
```

Comment: I think the php user has its own restrictions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The mode is also modified by the current umask, which you can change using umask().

cf. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

The umask is set to 0002 by default (at least at my system and on cli), that way the write-Bit is not set for everyone.